# AngularJs 'Wiring Up a Backend' Option to Edit not loading

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to get the 'Wire Up a Backend' example to work, but the options to add or edit a project don't show up. The search bar, project names and descriptions show up but not the icons to the right.

I've seen in other questions that not having 'ngRoute' or not deleting the slash at the end of the Firebae URL can cause problems, but I think I've accounted for both. The code I'm using is below; could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

EDIT; here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Emw0zu?p=info)

EDIT 2 : I added the Bootstrap and Font Awesome CDN links to the index.html and now the icons are showing up, but the edit page is still not working.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="project.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Projects</h2>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**details.html**

```
<form class="form-group" name="myForm">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.name.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="project.name" required>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.site.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="site">Site URL</label>
            <input type="url" class="form-control" name="site" ng-model="project.site" required>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.site.$error.required">Required</span>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.site.$error.url">Not a URL</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="project.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="destroy()" ng-show="project.$remove">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

**list.html**

```
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query"                 
            placeholder="Search">

        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th><a href="#/new"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | orderByPriority | filter:search |                 
        orderBy:'name'">
            <td><a href="{{project.site}}" target="_blank">{{project.name}}</a>                
        </td>
            <td>{{project.description}}</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**project.js**

```
angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

        .value('fbURL', 'https://angularjs-projects.firebaseio.com')

        .factory('Projects', function($firebase, fbURL) {
          return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL));
        })

        .config(function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
              controller:'ListCtrl',
              templateUrl:'list.html'
            })
            .when('/edit/:projectId', {
              controller:'EditCtrl',
              templateUrl:'detail.html'
            })
            .when('/new', {
              controller:'CreateCtrl',
              templateUrl:'detail.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo:'/'
            });
        })

        .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, Projects) {
          $scope.projects = Projects;
        })

        .controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, Projects) {
          $scope.save = function() {
            Projects.$add($scope.project, function() {
              $timeout(function() { $location.path('/'); });
            });
          };
        })

        .controller('EditCtrl',
          function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $firebase, fbURL) {
            var projectUrl = fbURL + $routeParams.projectId;
            $scope.project = $firebase(new Firebase(projectUrl));

            $scope.destroy = function() {
              $scope.project.$remove();
              $location.path('/');
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
              $scope.project.$save();
              $location.path('/');
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing that I could advise
shift this rule to bottom:

```
 .when('/', {
              controller:'ListCtrl',
              templateUrl:'list.html'
            })
```

or even do like so for the beginning

```
.otherwise( {
                  controller:'ListCtrl',
                  templateUrl:'list.html'
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists. I added the Bootstrap and Font Awesome CDN links to the index.html and now the icons are showing up, but the edit page is still broken.

Comment: unfortunately I can't play with url on plnkr. Probably another sandbox?

Comment: Ah I didn't make it public, here's a new public one; http://plnkr.co/edit/Emw0zu?p=info

Comment: The file is named `details.html`, yet in the template you refer to `detail.html`. Typo?

Comment: ...Thank you. I'll be in the corner of shame.